# Copyright name?

Tags: copyright

I know that I can protect my code and website if I put "Copyright [my name, surname]", but could I protect my code and website if I put "Copyright [website name or address]"? Would this practice be considered valid?

Comment: Can you explain how you know the first assertion of your question to be true?

Comment: Why do i need to explain it? It's the simplest way to indicate copyright because (In the US at least) when you make something(digital) you immediately gain copyright because YOU made it. It is your work!

Comment: Because if you could explain it you would know the answer to your question.

Comment: Why don't you just answer it?